# Create asterisk extension from my application

Tags: .net, asterisk

I am developing an .NET MVC application. Now i need to create asterisk pbx extension from my application rather than to create from asterisk dashboard. How can i do that? Please provide the code for the same.

I got php code for the same which is on https://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP/Bootstrap#Bootstrap-AnExample. But i need .net code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, "please provide code" is not  valid request on SO.

You can use asterisk REALTIME architecture, put your extensions in mysql.

However you need have basic knowledge about sip and trunk to do that.

Other option is create text files every X minutes, reload asterisk.

For more info about REALTIME see this

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip